# Im not understand how read JSON file from NFC tag using MFRC522

Tags: nfc, mfrc522

Im trying read data from NFC tag using MFRC522. I can read ID, SAK, ATQA ,ATS, but im not understand how read blocks data from tag and file JSON.interested in a simple sequence of commands performing a given task.
I have NFC type 4A Mifare plus.Reading ID is performed using functions Anticollision and Select.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mifare Plus [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1P(H)x2_SDS.pdf) just `Transceive` as you would do a a Mifare Classic 1/4K whose [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S70YYX_V1.pdf) Section 12 says `Transceive` `30h00h` to read block 0

As you don't specify how you are connecting to the MFRC522 and with what language, but you can read the ID, etc you must be familiar in sending commands like `Transceive` to it and getting data back.

How a JSON file is stored in the blocks is specific to your implementation (though it could be a propriety encoding of NDef only you will know by looking at it)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
Can you please tell me how to read NDEF?
I do not understand what I have to do after PPS answer.
If im tranceive 30h,00h,CRC1,CRC2; i receive same

Comment: with using NFC Tools programm  im tranceive ADPU command 00 A4 04 00 07 D2 76 00 00 85 01 01 00 and have answer 9000, but when im transcieve this command after PPS, nothing happens